# Reorganize Sequelize results

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm doing a complex `findAll` in Sequelize with lots of `includes`, like this.

```
const versions = yield Version.findAndCountAll({
  order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
  attributes: ['description', 'createdAt', 'id'],
  include: [{
    model: Section,
    attributes: ['slug'],
    where: { slug: section },
    include: [{
      model: Type,
      attributes: ['slug'],
      where: { slug: type },
      include: [{
        model: Group,
        attributes: ['slug'],
        where: { slug: group }
      }]
    }]
  }]
});
```

The results then come out like this:

```
{
  "description": "Wow. Nice one.",
  "createdAt": "2016-04-11T23:05:15.736Z",
  "body": "hi",
  "id": 10,
  "Section": {
    "slug": "ttyl",
    "Type": {
      "slug": "Test",
      "Group": {
        "slug": "python2",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The depth that their nested to makes the result a little unpleasant to work with. I'd like it more like this, if possible

```
{
  "description": "Wow. Nice one.",
  "createdAt": "2016-04-11T23:05:15.736Z",
  "body": "hi",
  "id": 10,
  "Section": "ttyl",
  "Type": "Test",
  "Group": "python2"
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to flatten to *some* extent by setting raw:true. Raw true will flatten to something like model.subproperty.property, etc, etc. The include 'as' option allows you to alias on these properties. but I do not believe you can automatically completely reshape the object (at least I have found nothing in the docs). From the example above, ultimately, I believe, you'd have to add your own mapping step.

```
Model.findAndCountAll({
  ...
}).then(function(results){
     return results.map(function(items){
         //map into another "object'
         //or into anonymous {};
     });
});
```

Comment: Can you copy the relevant part of the link you shared for posterity?

Comment: @Noah clarified/updated my comments regarding flattening.